# SQL delete query not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to delete the latest entries on a table, however the SQL query I'm using is simply not deleting anything at all. I used breakpoints and read the code several times, unable to find any errors, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString;
    var path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\connstring.txt";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        connectionString = sr.ReadLine();
    }

    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    MessageBox.Show("Um grupo de trabalhadores, está agora  a apagar os seus dados, aguarde.");

    string queryString = string.Empty;
    using (connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc IN (SELECT TOP 100 numdoc  FROM WGCDOCCAB   WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()),120) ORDER BY numdoc DESC)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        command.Connection.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Apesar de cansados e sujos os trabalhadores mandam avisar que foi tudo apagado!");
```

Comment: A Command should be executed. Call command.ExecuteNonQuery after the initialization

Comment: The WHERE clause must return an empty set.  Better to go into the database console, run the query, and see why that would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is calling [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the `command`:

```
int deletionCount = command.ExexuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Deleted {0} items", deletionCount);
```

Next you need to make sure that the command itself is closed, not its connection. The connection is closed by the `using` statement, so you do not need to worry about it.

The code should look like this after the change:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Um grupo de trabalhadores, está agora  a apagar os seus dados, aguarde.");
    string queryString = string.Empty;
    queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc IN (SELECT TOP 100 numdoc  FROM WGCDOCCAB   WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()),120) ORDER BY numdoc DESC)";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection)) {
        int deletionCount = command.ExexuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted "+deletionCount+" items");
    }
}
```

This code should display `Deleted 100 items` if the table contains 100 matching records, or the actual number of the deleted records if there are fewer than 100 matching records in your table.

Comment: Thank you sir that did it! Clear explanation and quality code, best way for a rookie to learn :)